# Mapping Entity objects by database schema in intelij generates bad annotations and relations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have followin sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `power_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) 
ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `power_id` (`power_id`),

ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_user_power` FOREIGN KEY (`power_id`) REFERENCES `power` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

CREATE TABLE `power` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` date NOT NULL
)
```

( its hand typed )
However when i do `view Persistence -> Generate Persistance Mapping -> By Database Schema` It generated this in User entity class:

```
private PowerEntity powerByPowerId;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "power_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
public PowerEntity getPowerByPowerId() {
    return powerByPowerId;
}
```

which is clearly 1:n relation ( e.g multiple users have one power ) while sql says about 1:1 relation.

NOw i am unsure if my sql is wrong or intelij generated wrong relatios.

How to deal with it? My database schema is not small and so far i have noticed only this mistake, however i am not sure if its my fault or intelij's mapping is producing wrong entity tables ( which would mean i could find another badly generated entity ).

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you considered that you can have multiple records in your power table with the same id?  And that - as a consequence - the ManyToOne is not inaccurate?  And yes - I am misreading this.  Sorry.

Comment: the power_id is unique field, so you cannt have more users with same power_id

Comment: That is indeed true, however in that case it would be @onetomany - the mapping doesnt make sense too, or i am missinterpreting something

Comment: What's the database? When you generate table you can see the relationship IDE will create for the FK. If you believe this is bug, feel free to report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample to reproduce. Please specify your database.

Comment: @Andrey I am running MySql 5.6. Thats what i am not sure about, if its bug or there is flaw in my sql ( thus the question ).

Comment: What type do you have for this relationship shown in dialog? See https://www.dropbox.com/s/smh5nexr0ovqnn3/Import%20Database%20Schema%202018-08-14%2009-42-54.png?dl=0

Comment: @Andrey I am unable to check it now, i will do it later and let you know. However your screenshot shows Collection which is also wrong, or am i wrong?